# A question about using the loc method to create a new column based on existing columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-manipulation

I have two dataframes named df and df2 with the same number of rows. I would like to create a new column in df based on some logical comparison as  follows

```py
df['new_col']='nothing'

df.loc[(df2['col2'].isna()) & (df2['col2'].isna()) & (~df['col'].isna()), 'new_col'] = df['col3']
```

It seems the above code works fine for my purpose. However my expectation was I will get an error due to
mismatching of columns on both sides of "=". The right side is putting an entire column (with size of df rows) into a subset of the new_col columns! I am really confused now! Am I missing something here?

Comment: Pandas indexing works by assigning to those entries which match over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a Series in an assignment, pandas performs index alignment internally. This ensures that both sides of the `=` have the same length and the same order of indices.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3]})
# different order, missing indices, extra indices
s = pd.Series({2: 30, 0: 10, 4: 40})
df['B'] = s
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A     B
0  1  10.0
1  2   NaN
2  3  30.0
```

If you used a list or array, then an exact matching length would be needed.

```
# runs fine
df['C'] = [1,2,3]

# triggers error
df['C'] = [1,2]
# ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (3)
```

Comment: Thanks! So something like ``` df3['A'] =df4['B'] ``` always get executed without an error?

Comment: @Redshoes that's correct.